# Best Option for Training Sandbox

Tags: sandbox

I am looking to use a sandbox specifically for Training for SFDC. My client does not want to purchase a full sandbox due to high cost. I would like to have "real data" available for the training. What are the best options for a lower cost sandbox for training with consideration to having a fair amount of user licenses, account/record data, and territory data?

Comment: Might be of interest: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48313/possible-approaches-to-dedicated-training-environments

Answer (score 2):

[Sandbox Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=create_test_instance.htm&language=en_US)

Here you can see an overview of the existing sandbox types. If you need to have production data in your sandbox environment, you will need to access a Partial Copy Sandbox or a Full Sandbox. 
Consequently, about the pricing, there are not so many alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a longer question about this some weeks ago. As an unfortunate, there is no really good solution for my taste. Just have a look here:

[What is the Best Practice for the right Training Environment?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53832/what-is-the-best-practice-for-the-right-training-environment)

I'm not happy with this situation and I would really appreciate if some of the Salesforce trainers would share their experience and approaches to setup something with a reasonable effort. My guess is, they still have some blacktab-magic to let it rock.

Especially for the PE customers for me it's bloody work so far with manual preparation and ETL jobs...